# Use Windows Firewall to block ports in vmware workstation

Tags: networking, firewall, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I have a windows 10 computer that is running a virtual machine with "vmware workstation 12". That windows computer is connected directly to my modem; therefore, I can host my website by allowing port 80 on the firewall.

Comcast, my internet service provider has enabled me to use 2 public ip addresses. As a result my windows 10 computer (host) has the ip address 170.55.7.10 and my virtual machine has the ip address 170.55.7.11. That is because I have the following settings on my vm machine:
[image]

**Now my question is** why when I add firewall rules to my windows 10 computer they do not reflect on my virtual machine. For example if I block an ip address, that ip address is only blocked on my windows 10 computer but now on my virtual machine. How can I add firewall rules to my windows 10 computer and have them be reflected on my virtual machine?

Comment: "why when I add firewall rules to my windows 10 computer they do not reflect on my virtual machine." Because they are two separate machines.  "How can I add firewall rules to my windows 10 computer and have them be reflected on my virtual machine?" Configure a VM to act as a firewall for both machines and block the website within that

Comment: How do I configure a VM to act as a firewall for both machines? Thanks for the help